# How to move an object using Users Finger Touch/Drag in Android

Tags: android, gesture, android-gesture

I am developing an app in which I need to implement object movement following by users finger touch/drag. My object is at the bottom of the screen and it can move horizontal only. I have no idea about Gesture control or Object movement in Android.
Also, the object should maintain its state, for example if user stops dragging the object  it should appear to its last position only. 
I need to sort this out, any help would be appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: What object you want to move? any view like button or Imageview etc?

Comment: its just an ImageView

Comment: here is a tutorial for you then http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm

Comment: Hi @QadirHussain, I have checked the link but its a bit jerky and even sometimes its not picking the image sometimes when user touch the image. Can you help with that ?

Comment: image will be picked on LongClick in this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdxdTkdNkVs

than have a look on this:

https://github.com/fouady/SpotifyTray-Android